# Comment on a profile

Tags: support, comments, profile-page

I know it is possible to comment on someone's question or answer, but is it possible to ask a question about or on his profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Comments are for improving or clarifying questions and answers, not for general banter with another user.

Chat is a more informal alternative that may get you what you want.